# k-fold cross validation for trial based data sets

Tags: modeling, cross-validation

My EEG dataset contains the data of some subjects and each subject has 4 parts.
The main paper used the following method:
It used two parts for the subject. the first part was used as training data and the second part was used as the test set.
I want to use k-fold cross validation but I need to pay attention to the condition of paper's method (part 1 as training set and part 2 as testing set).
First of all, I need to separate my data into k parts then use k-1 part as train and 1 other as test and do this process in a k-loop.
my data is in two separate parts, how can I see two part in a one part? is it possible to mix the data?
If I mix them how should I use the condition of paper?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your question is very vague! and you did not explain what the conditions are or should be.
Anyway, in K-Fold your data is uniformly partitioned into k equally sized subsamples. Of these k subsamples, each time a single subsample is separated and used as your validation set and the rest are used as  your training set. This process is repeated k times (the folds), until all of the partitions are used as validation only once. Then the k results from the folds can be averaged to produce a single estimation.

I don't precisely get what you meant by subject, but if the paper used part 1 and two for training and testing(validation) respectively , you can do either of the following:

1. You may combine these  two parts and then apply K-fold on  this newly merged dataset.
2. Set aside the test data(second part), run k-fold on the first part and thus you will be having k-1 fold for your training, 1 for validation
   which you use for finding/fine tuning your parameters/network/model,
   and one test set which you ultimately use for testing